# Count number of leading characters of a specific character at the beginning of a string?

Tags: php

Given a string such as:

```
$a = '00023407283';
$b = 'f045602345';
```

Is there a built in function that can count the number of occurrences of a specific character starting at the beginning and continuing until it finds a different character that is not specified?

Given the above, and specifying zero (`0`) as the character, the expected result would be:

```
$a = '00023407283'; // 3 (the other zeros don't count)
$b = 'f0045602345'; // 0 (It does not start with zero)
```

Comment: Preg_match('/^0+/',$a, $match) should return the substring I  the $match variable. Take the length of it and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
function count_leading($haystack,$value) {
    $i = 0;
    $mislead = false;
    while($i < strlen($haystack) && !$mislead) {
        if($haystack[$i] == $value) {
            $i += 1;
        } else {
            $mislead = true;
        }
    }
    return $i;
}

//examples
echo count_leading('aaldfkjlk','a'); //returns 2
echo count_leading('dskjheelk','c'); //returns 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built-in functions that could do that (it's too specific) but you could write a method to do that

```
function repeatChar($string, $char) {
     $pos = 0;
     while($string{$pos} == $char) $pos++;
     return $pos;
}
```

Comment: But there is: `strspn`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want [`strspn`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php), which counts the number of characters from the second argument at the beginning of the first argument:

```
echo strspn($a, '0'); // === 3
echo strspn($b, '0'); // === 0
```

See it live at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YqgvN). Besides being a built-in (read "fast"), this also accepts any number of single characters to look at the beginning. However, note that the function is byte-oriented, so it will not work as expected for multi-byte characters.